# Magento 2: How to move block inside a new container in layout XML?

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to wrap the `.product-info-main` div on the product page inside a new container div (`.product-info-container`). After following the Magento [layout instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html), it's not behaving as expected. Here's what I have in `catalog_product_view.xml` right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-container" before="-"/>
            <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.container"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The layout doesn't change at all. However, if I remove the `<referenceContainer>` level, then it works as expected, but the `.product-info-container` div is inserted at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Try putting the 'move ' outside the referenceContainer?

Comment: @WilliamOakley That fixed it -- thanks :). If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the 'move' outside the referenceContainer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.container"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-container" before="-"/>            
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is it possible to move one specific section to top of the page, i am using https://store-locator-m2.magento-demo.amasty.com/amlocator/summercenter if add description all are coming below the map, i need only one section the slider should be come to the top I mean right after breadcrumbs. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbUIo.png, i am using page builder for creating description.

Comment: @zus Take a look at the layout files within the extension. This will let you know which blocks are being placed where and then you should be able to move them. Otherwise you may be able to override the template files to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.container"/>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <container name="product.info.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-container" before="-"/>            
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikunj Vadariya. William Oakley actually provided the answer first in the comment above, so as a courtesy I'll wait for him to post his comment as an answer. If he doesn't bother after a day, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: oh ok Np :) @10basetom